# How to use $\sqrt{1+|x+y|^2}\le(\sqrt{1+|2x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|2y|^2})/2$ to prove $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$?

Tags: inequality

How to use $\sqrt{1+|x+y|^2} \leq \left(\sqrt{1+|2x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|2y|^2}\right)/2$ to prove the triangle inequality $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$? I tried several methods but still had no idea.

Comment: $|1+1|^2 = 4.  \; \; \; $  $|1|^2 + |1|^2  = 2$

Comment: I have to ask, how on earth do you know $\sqrt{1 +|x+y|^2} \le \frac {\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}2$ in the first place?  And... what's wrong with just completely ignoring $\sqrt{1 +|x+y|^2} \le \frac {\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}2$ and proving $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$ by more obvious means.  Are you sure you aren't supposed to go the *other* way and use $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$ to prove  $\sqrt{1 +|x+y|^2} \le \frac {\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}2$?

Comment: Thank you! I am sure it asks to prove from the complex to the simple form.. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method :

It simply proves this  :

$$\sqrt{1 + |x + y|^2} > |x+y| $$

You can prove this too easily :

$$ |x| > \sqrt{1+|2x|^2}/2  \land  |y| > \sqrt{1+|2y|^2 }/2$$

And therefore :

$$|x| + |y| > \sqrt{1+|2x|^2} /2+ \sqrt{1+|2y|^2 }/2$$

Finally we have :

$$|x+y | < \sqrt{1 + |x + y|^2} < \sqrt{1+|2x|^2} /2+ \sqrt{1+|2y|^2 } /2< |x| + |y| $$

And here we are done :

$$|x+y| < |x| + |y| $$